# Delphi FMX: DisposeOf control work in windows paltform but not working in Android. what's the problem?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I create a button at runtime and set onclick event same as below:

```
BDel := TButton.Create(CR);//CR is Tpanel
BDel.Parent := CR;
BDel.Position.Y := 115;
BDel.Width := 120;
BDel.Height := 32;
BDel.Position.X := 150;
BDel.Text := 'Delete Panel';
BDel.OnClick := BdelClick;
```

Button is inside the Panel. onClick procedure is as below:

```
procedure TForm1.BdelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  tt: TPanel;
begin
    tt := ((Sender as TButton).Parent as TPanel);
    tt.DisposeOf;
end;
```

This code worked properly in windows platform and button with its parent removed but not worked in Android.  What's the problem?

Comment: To add more information, you should edit your question instead of writng a comment. Please do it now and delete your comment.

Comment: For `fmx` questions it is good idea to also indicate which Delphi version you are using, as there has been many development steps.

Comment: I use Delphi 10.3 community edition latest update.

Comment: It is not safe to destroy a control (or its parent) directly inside an event handler of that control. In this case, I would use `TThread.ForceQueue()` or equivalent to delay the destruction until after the event handler exits first, eg: `tt := ...; TThread.ForceQueue(nil, tt.DisposeOf);`

Answer (score 0):

You need clear all link for object.

```
(Sender as TButton).Parent:= nil;
tt.DisposeOf;
tt:= nil;
```